# Problem: Visual C MFC Dialog editor “Failed to return new Code Element. Possibly syntax error. New Element Name test”

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, tinyxml2

I have a simple MFC application, using Visual Studio 2019. My problem is that when I want to add a variable to any control I get the pop up message:

> Failed to return new Code Element. Possibly syntax error. New Element Name test

[image: Screenshot of error]

To clarify: The problem is in the Visual C MFC Dialog Editor. Not in my code as it runs fine. I have tried all possible solutions that I found using Google. Nothing helps. The app is very simple. The only "extra" is that I am using `tinyxml2`.

What I found out by Google is that this is not a new problem, and the solution was to not use **precompiled headers**. And I am not using precompiled headers. so...

I am stuck. A long shot: Note the "Element" in the error text, and all the "elements" in tinyxml2. Some collision of symbols ??

I hint (maybe): I have got this message once before when I was using a long variable name. I shorted the name and the error was gone.
This is my second try. When the problem turned up I removed all changes since it was OK. But the problem is still there. Somthing I did has left some, not reversable, mark in the code (or database).

Comment: Sometimes the class wizard can get messed up. ?I have found that shutting down VS, renaming your folder and then renaming it back, triggers a rebuild of the class wizard database and sometimes cleans up issues like this. Otherwise is best to direct your issue to MS via the Feedback mechanism.

Comment: You are not exactly clear because you refer to dialog editor, then tiny xml data files. Please be specific. Are you creating a variable? How are you creating it? Can you show any screenshot?

Comment: Ok tried renaming, still problem.  "then tiny xml data files", No data files,I just added tinyxml2 to the project, Just metioned it cus thats the only non-MS code in the projekt.   I am using the dialig editor to add variables [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3cswi9fwpm3xua/MFCError.png?dl=0)

Comment: So, it sound sliek a Classwizard related issue. I suggest taking it up with Microsoft via teh built in support.

Comment: Ho and behold: I started the VC2017 I still have installed. and in 2017 it works as expected. Methink I stay with 2017 :)   Maybe I will try a reinstallation of 2019 later

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that (at least in my case) deleting the .APS file,
i.e. "<your solution>.aps",
remedied the situation.

I'm using VS 2022.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

0

I discovered that (at least in my case) deleting the .APS file, i.e. ".aps", remedied the situation. Swapping back and forth between two versions of a dialog, the dialog editor can get out of sync for the current .RC code. Removing the .APS file and reloading the solution and opening the dialog editor for this dialog fixes this issue.

I'm using VS 2012.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).